# HTML <cite> inside link?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've always used HTML `<cite>` directly with a citation, and then if I want to link to that, I put the link *around* the citation, like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/"><cite>Example Citation></cite></a>
```

To me this seems most logical, because a link is not part of the citation—I'm using the citation in a link.

But in HTML [5.2 § 4.5.6. The meta element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element) the examples use just the opposite:

```
<cite><a href="http://example.com/">Example Citation></a></cite>
```

Does the HTML specification allow us to place the `<cite>` inside the `<a>`? Does the HTML specification indicate a preference, or are the examples indicating otherwise merely an arbitrary arrangement?

Comment: both are phrase content and both are permitted inside of other elemnt

Answer (score 2):

See [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element).

The content model of `a` is:

> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

Transparent means that it inherits the content model of the parent element.

```
<!parent>
    <cite><a>...</a></cite>
    <a><cite>...</cite></a>
<!parent>
```

So if the first example there is valid (i.e. the parent element of the `<cite>` is somewhere that a `<cite>` element is allowed), then swapping them around is also perfectly valid.

---

Since the destination of the link is part of the citation, putting the link inside the cite element makes more sense from a semantic point of view.

Comment: "Since the destination of the link is part of the citation, putting the link inside the cite element makes more sense from a semantic point of view." My thought has always been, "Everything in `<cite>` is the name of the title, and the original title didn't have a link in it, so I shouldn't have a link inside the `<cite>`. In other words, I want to link _to_ the thing being cited—the thing I'm cited doesn't have a link in it." But maybe I'm not thinking of `<cite>` completely correctly. Maybe it only indicates _my_ citation. But then what would distinguish the actual title inside `<cite>`?

Comment: @GarretWilson — "name of the title" — That's where you are wrong. See the spec: [The cite element represents a reference to a creative work. It must include the title of the work or the name of the author (person, people or organization) or an URL reference, or a reference in abbreviated form as per the conventions used for the addition of citation metadata.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element). The location of the resource is something that should be referenced. "But then what would distinguish the actual title" — HTML doesn't expect you to distinguish that.

Comment: I don't see where my use is "wrong" as you say. The spec allows me to include the title inside `<cite>`. I was just saying that I use `<cite>` to delimit the actual title as well. What you're saying is that the HTML concept of `<cite>` is broader than just the title, it's the entire citation, and that HTML has nothing specific to delimit the title itself within the citation. That's for the clarification. That doesn't mean its wrong for me to use `<cite>` specifically for the title and place the link around it. Too bad HTML doesn't allow `<cite><a><title>…</title></a></cite>`.